# What is this kitchen device?

Tags: equipment

What is the kitchen device shown here? I found it in the kitchen and it is about 18 inches long.

[image]

Comment: Information such as any writing, etching on the tool or information on when and where it was bought might help identify.

Comment: Could it be a cheese slicer?

Comment: To me that looks like it's the handle for something, and that this 'something' is supposed to slide over the wires - the springiness of the wires holding it on. Similarly to the way in which a paint roller can be separated into the handle (with springy wires) and the actual roller (a cylinder which slides over the wires).

Comment: I'm actually thinking something that is meant to stretch muslin or other cloth for sifting, but not really sure.

Comment: Definitely not a cheese slicer. the idea of being used for muslin or cheesecloth skimming is intriguing, but looking at the protrusions on both ends, I think Brhans is right, I think it clips into a wire basket of some kind, possibly for deep frying.

Comment: This looks like a duster to me. I have one that looks identical; it has a microfiber cloth with a pocket that slips over the wires. Similar to https://www.amazon.com/OXO-Good-Grips-Microfiber-Duster/dp/B00940DV6W.

Comment: @brhans : I suspect ceejayoz is correct, but you might also be able to use it with a roll of cling film to wrap things up, like you suggest

Answer (score 4):

I actually think that is an old-style duster handle, not a food processing tool. Used with disposable dusting units with a tube that slides over then handle.  It is clearly not for cooking IMHO. 
Something like this more modern unit. I could be wrong, but that's certainly what it looks like>
[image]